# Packaging a QGIS Project with vector and raster data for use on QField

Tags: vector-layer, qfield, raster-dataset

Does anyone have a step by step guide on how to package a QGIS project in QField and successfully open the project on a tablet?

Currently I have a QGIS project with vector layers and Google Satellite base map.
I then package the project using the QField synch plugin and copy across to my device saving under the followuing directory, Galaxy Tab Active\Tablet\Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\share\QGIS Projects.
When I open the project in QField the vector layers appear but the there is no Google Satellite base map visible, which I need to use offline.

Is there a key step I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have ported a project I created in QGIS to QField successfully. Although it did not have a Google satellite layer it did have a WFS layer hosted on my own server. All I did was make the project portable as described here [Making QGIS Project Portable](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/portable-project.html), then copied the project to my android device. If you are using a Google satellite layer then your project will not be able to work offline unless you use the image as a static raster layer so I am not sure I understand you on this point.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. How would I make the Google Satellite a static raster layer so that I can use it offline on my device? I've had problems successfully copying virtual raster layers to my device previously.

Comment: I have no direct experience with this but this link https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html mentions that you can export high resolution images from Google Earth Pro. You can add this as a raster layer in your QGIS project. A free source I have used before is Landsat Imagery but it could be very out of date depending on the area you are interested in.